# System.Web.HttpRequest Request - change http protocol version - http 2.0 request

Tags: asp.net

Does HttpRequest support setting the protocol version? I would like to set it to 2.0. Is it possible?

For example, HttpWebRequest has a ProtocolVersion property, but can only be set to 1.0 or 1.1.

Does HttpRequest use any default version? Will it work with HTTP/2?

If my server only supports HTTP/2, will I get an error if I use HttpRequest?

The company is going to be updating systems, to be compatible with HTTP/2. I am looking at some code, and we use HttpRequest, and I have noticed there is no option to set the protocol version. Will this be an issue?

I have also noticed in the code we specify:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: In any modern software you write in using .NET, you should always use `HttpClient`, all the other methods are legacy/obsolete/deprecated.

Comment: I am just updating some legacy code unfortunately.

Comment: HTTP 2.0 support in .NET Framework 4.6.2 version only: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42757481/how-to-sent-http-2-0-request-in-visual-c/42757773 and supported .NET Core 3.0 or newer

Comment: can you describe briefly the functionality.What is the request object used for?